# Inserting new record into ACCESS with ASP - issue with parameters

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I have created a simple ASP page in Expression Web 4 and have a textbox  to ask end user for an activity. I am trying to insert the entered activity name into an access database using ASP.Net connections.

When I load the webpage and enter a value in the textbox...and hit refresh, it won't send the entered value to ACCESS.

The Database is called '**BookingDB**'.  The table is called '**tbl_Booking**'.
Two fields exist therein (Fields: Customer and Activity)

***Customer***: *PK* and *Autonumber*.

***Activity***: *Short Text*.

On Webpage, the textbox is named **txtActivity**.

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p>
    <asp:TextBox id="txtActivity" runat="server" Height="29px" Width="153px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AccessDataSource id="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" DataFile="BookingDB.mdb" SelectCommand="INSERT INTO [tbl_Booking] ([Activity]) VALUES (?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtActivity" Name="Act_Parameter" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: You cant hit refresh to submit/save data, you need a way to submit it from the form so the code knows when to execute

Comment: If I remove the parameters and put in raw values , it works fine. Just not accepting parameter values unfortunately